# Determining if an extension is a normal extension [MORANDI'S BOOK]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm dealing with the following problem:

> Let $K$ be a field and suppose that $\sigma\in\mbox{Aut}(K)$ has infinite order. Let $F$ be the fixed field of $\sigma$. If $K/F$ is algebraic, show that $K$ is normal over $F$.

${\it Proof. }$ Let $\alpha\in K$, I want to show that $f(x)=\mbox{min}(F,\alpha)$ splits over $K$. Let $i\in \mathbb{N}$, notice that $f(\sigma^i(\alpha))=\sigma^i(f(\alpha))=\sigma^i(0)=0$, thus $\sigma^i(\alpha)$ is a root of $f(x)$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider $n$ the minimal integer such that $\sigma^n(\alpha)=\alpha$ ($n$ exists since we have a finite number of roots of $f$), then we can factor $f$ over $K$ as $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))...(x-\sigma^n(\alpha))g(x)$ where $g(x)\in K$, moreover, since $f=\sigma(f)$, we have

$$(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))...(x-\sigma^n(\alpha))g(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))...(x-\sigma^n(\alpha))\sigma(g(x))$$

and therefore $\sigma(g)=g$, thus $g(x)\in F[x]$, this implies that the factorization of $f$ is a factorization over $F$, hence $g(x)=1$ since $f$ is irreducible over $F$ and so $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\sigma(\alpha))...(x-\sigma^n(\alpha))$, i.e., $f$ splits over $K$.

Is this proof correct? If that's the case... Where did I use the infinite order of $\sigma$? Because if the proof is correct, it seems I've proved something like "There are not irreducible polynomials of order $n$ in a fixed field of an automorphism of order less than $n$". Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think that the infinite order of $\sigma$ is "used" at the statement "If $K/F$ is algebraic": in fact, if $\sigma$ has finite order, then $F$ is the fixed field of the finite group $\langle\sigma\rangle$, so by Artin theorem the field extension $K/F$ is Galois (and Aut$(K/F)=\langle\sigma\rangle)$; by the way, the proof of this result is along the same lines of your reasoning above.

Comment: I think that $n$ may be $n-1$ in the expression of  $f(X)$ @Daniel

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Can you state the Artin theorem?? I haven't learnt about it..

Comment: @ZWJ If $K/F$ is **any** field extension and $H$ is a *finite* subgroup of Aut$(K/F)$, then $K/K^H$ is Galois, with Galois group equal to $H$.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see this in my first answer: you are using that $K/F$ is algebraic from the very beginning! because you reason about the *minimal* polynomial of an arbitrary element $\alpha\in K$, and this is possible only if you assume beforehand that $\alpha$ is $F$-algebraic.